# i was trying to deploy my job on tomcat but it keeps showing me this error : No wars found. Deploy aborted

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, deployment, war

i've got this error while trying to deploy my job on tomcat 
[image]

i checked my JENKINS_HOME and my workspace i checked my sample.war file 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit tomcat-users.xml
In order for Tomcat to accept remote deployments, you have to add a user with the role manager-script. To do so, edit the file ../conf/tomcat-users.xml and add the following line:

```
<user username="deployer" password="deployer" roles="manager-script" />
```

Ensure you have the selected the correct tomcat version.
Save the configuration and run your job.

Comment: i have already added a user with the manager-script role and it keeps showing me the same error i selected the correct tomcat version too

Comment: @YassineSoltani The context path doesn't appear to be correct. Try giving / or remove the .war and leave it to sample in the context path.

You should choose a Context Path in which the application should be installed. It would rename the WAR file before deploying to the server and thereby the application context root would be changed.

Comment: i fugured out the problem 
the user that i have created was between <!--  <user>   --> so it was a comment and i didn't pay enough attention x) thanx for your help